# Updating a Dash Callback using RadioItems

Tags: callback, radio-button, plotly-dash

I am fairly new to python coding so I apologize in advance for my ignorance. I am trying to create a Dash App that drops outliers using standard deviation. The user selects a standard deviation using RadioItem inputs.

My question is what amendments do I need to make to my code so that the  RadioItem value updates max_deviations using a callback?

Import packages, clean the data and define a query

```
import dash
import plotly.express as px
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server

df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\SVS_GIS\POWER BI\CSV_DATA\QSAS2021.csv', encoding='unicode_escape')

#SET DATE OF VALUATION
df['TIME'] = ((pd.to_datetime(df['Sale Date'], dayfirst=True)
             .rsub(pd.to_datetime('01/10/2021', dayfirst=True))
             .dt.days
          )*-1)

df=df[df['TIME'] >= -365]

df = df.query("(SMA >=1 and SMA <= 3) and (LGA==60)")
```

prepare dataframe for dropping outliers

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
x = df.TIME
y = df.CHANGE
mean = np.mean(y)
standard_deviation = np.std(y)
distance_from_mean = abs(y - mean)
```

app layout

```
app.layout = html.Div([

html.Label("Standard Deviation Picker:", style={'fontSize':25, 'textAlign':'center'}),
    html.Br(),
       html.Label("1.0 = 68%, 2.0 = 95%, 3.0 = 99.7%", style={'fontSize':15, 
'textAlign':'center'}),
    
html.Div(id="radio_items"),
 dcc.RadioItems(      
options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]],
value=2.0
),          

html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id="the_graph")]
)])
```

callback

```
@app.callback(
    Output("the_graph", "figure"),
    Input("radio_items", 'value')
)
def update_graph(max_deviations):
    not_outlier = distance_from_mean < max_deviations * standard_deviation
    no_outliers = y[not_outlier]
    trim_outliers = pd.DataFrame(data=no_outliers)
    dff = pd.merge(trim_outliers, df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
    return (dff)


    fig = px.scatter(dff, x='TIME', y='CHANGE_y',
                     
                     color ='SMA',
                     trendline='ols',
                     size='PV',
                     height=500,
                     width=800,
                     hover_name='SMA',

                     )
    return dcc.Graph(id='the_graph', figure=fig)


    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Comment: Is the section where you build the graph supposed to be indented inside the callback? Because it looks like it should be.

Comment: I have fixed the code as per your suggestion, now getting a TypeError

Comment: `max_deviations` isn't a vector, perhaps that's why that line isn't working?

Comment: I made some amendments to the code today. Now when I manually add the standard deviation to >print(update_graph("standard deviations 1.0, 2.0 or 3.0))<,  the code returns the correct data each time. Somehow I need to connect max_deviations with radio_items value. The code appears OK up to the callback

Answer (score 1):

Your `dcc.RadioItems` doesn't have an `id` prop. Add that, and make sure it matches the ID given in the callback, and you should be good.

Comment: Thankyou for answering coralvanda, the code now works!!!